# "They knew what mercy is" vs. "they knew what mercy was"

Tags: verbs, tenses, past-tense, present-tense, past-vs-present

> They knew what mercy is.
>   They knew what mercy was.

*Mercy* is something that always exists so can I say *is*  as in the quoted example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [He didn't know where New Jersey was…](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/), [Tense change: previous actions on something that's currently true](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16388/), [Should we use past tense here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/), and [Should I say 'What I wanted to say is' or 'What I wanted to say was'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/).

Answer (score 3):

I think it sounds more correct to use the same tense as the subject - so, in this case

simple past

> They **knew** what mercy **was**.

simple present

> They **know** what mercy **is**.

Answer (score 1):

Mercy is something that exists always but everyone tends to understand it differently. For one person it is when you kill your wounded horse for another it is to try and heel it. It is not necessary that mercy is always the same thing even for one man. As times change, he may change his mind.

Therefore, they knew what mercy *was* and they could not know what it would be 10 years later.