# Present or Past tense to describe a past condition which is still present?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, past-tense, present-tense, past-vs-present

Scenario: My friend John has a personality disorder, intensely paranoid for example.

Can I say:

> There were three events last year that told me John *had* a problem.

or can I say:

> There were threee events last year that told me John *has* a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tense change: previous actions on something that's currently true](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16388/), [He didn't know where New Jersey was](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/), [Should I use “is” or “was” in this example?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/), [Should we use past tense here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/), and [Should I say 'What I wanted to say is' or 'What I wanted to say was'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4411/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with mgkrebbs in the case of storytelling.  In conversation, however, if I say:

> There were three events last year that told me John *had* a problem.

I am implying that he had a problem last year but that the problem is no longer present.  If I say:

> There were three events last year that told me John *has* a problem.

I am implying that the problem existed last year and continues into the present.

Might I also suggest the following (assuming the problem still exists):

> Three events last year told me John has a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two alternatives, the correct one is *There were three events last year that told me John had a problem.*  It should not be phrased with *has* because the verb *told* is in the past, so it must have told you about something in the past (i.e. *John had a problem*). It says nothing about whether the problem is or is not currently present.

Comment: But what if I said : 'Look, John is sick, there were three events last year that told me John has a problem.'

Comment: You could say that without raising eyebrows; it would be more or less understood.  In a way, it might be taken as a shorter form of _John is sick. There were three events last year that told me John was having a problem._  If you want to say he is now having a problem, you could say something like _John is sick. There were three events last year that tell me John has a problem._ or _...is having a problem_.

Comment: It sounds a lot more strained to say *There were three events last year that tell me...* than to say *Three events last year told me he has a problem*. Possibly the best way is to avoid the issue: *John has a problem: three events last year told me so.*