# I didn't know he IS/WAS

Tags: grammar

I didn't know he was/is such a good person.

Which is correct in the above sentence. Is/was and why ?

(Assume the person is still alive and is still a good person)

Comment: Grammatically, both are perfectly valid and defensible. But *idiomatically*, native speakers would invariably choose to match past tense *didn't know* with ***was*** in this specific context.

Comment: [Present or Past tense to describe a past condition which is still present?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17982/present-or-past-tense-to-describe-a-past-condition-which-is-still-present), [Tense change: previous actions on something that's currently true](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16388/tense-change-previous-actions-on-something-thats-currently-true)

Comment: Actually, better is this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/he-didnt-know-where-new-jersey-was

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct depending on the context

I didn't know he was a good person: He could have moved to a new town or you could've just met him and thought he was trying to do something wrong,  not realizing he was being nice, and get yourself in trouble

Though I didn't know He is a good person is probably better because you could've just met him.