# "The only thing they forgot to teach us is/was how to be a student." Which is right? "Is" or "was"?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-tense

Which sounds correct?

> The only thing they forgot to teach *is* how to be a student.

Or

> The only thing they forgot to teach *was* how to be a student.

Comment: The linked answer does not answer this question. The accepted answer there is a response to the condition included in that question's example. There is no such condition here, and the accepted answer's "would" (describing what happens if the condition is satisfied) doesn't apply here.

Comment: There's probably a difference depending on whether you lacked student knowledge then, or lack it now. (The tense of the rest of the passage would similarly be relevant.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Present or Past tense to describe a past condition which is still present?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17982/present-or-past-tense-to-describe-a-past-condition-which-is-still-present)

Comment: Though _is_ is arguably justified because the 'how to be a student' problem is still extant in general, even if the speaker has now overcome this, I'd say that in this case the pull of the past teaching informs the use of _was_. However, _is_ is not wrong, especially if the speaker feels they are still disadvantaged.  But I'd still say this is a duplicate.